# Android SQLiteDiskIOException disk I/O error. But only one place opens the db in my code

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is part of my trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to create application kula.publics.objects.KulaApplication: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error: COMMIT;
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5116)
......
Caused by:
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDiskIOException:disk I/O error: COMMIT;
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(Unknown Source)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(Unknown Source)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(Unknown Source)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(Unknown Source)
kula.third.afinal.b.c(Unknown Source)
kula.third.afinal.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
kula.third.afinal.b.b(Unknown Source)
kula.third.afinal.b.a(Unknown Source)
kula.third.afinal.b.a(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.db.FlySubDbManager.getDb(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.db.FlyBaseDbManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.db.FlySubDbManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.db.FlySubDbManager.init(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.KulaFlyController.<init>(Unknown Source)
kula.eric.data.KulaFlyController.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have checked my code, there is only one place to open the db file. It doesn't look like multi-threaded problem. And the crash mostly happened in Android 4.4.4.

Related library:

`SQLiteOpenHelper` in sqlcipher:

https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/blob/master/src/net/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteOpenHelper.java

`FinalDb` in afinal:

https://github.com/yangfuhai/afinal/blob/master/src/net/tsz/afinal/FinalDb.java

Comment: Post your DBHelper class

Comment: @AkhileshPatil, I have posted. I have modify the afinal library to use sqlcipher in my project.

Comment: "disk I/O error" means that the flash storage is broken. This is probably not a software problem.

Comment: @CL. Lots of our user have this crash. I don't think their flash storage are all broken.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Michael. I don't know how to solve.

Comment: I got this issue in the first time launch app (after install), or after clearing data. Not sure how to fix yet. 
BTW any updates?